# Adding Local Port to existing Windows firewall rule

Tags: batch-file, netsh

I have inbound firewall rule setup that has some local TCP ports open. These ports are configurable and can be changed (at the moment they are 2501 and 4300) 
I'm trying write a simple batch script that would add additional port to this existing rule.
I have tried:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=%RULE_NAME% new localport=%PORT%
```

but that command overwrites my current ports in the rule leaving only new one (%PORT%). 
Also tried:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=%RULE_NAME% dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=%PORT%
```

but this one is creating new rule (of same name). This could work, but it looks kind of ugly.

Is there a command that would just add %PORT% to existing ports. Or can I somehow save current ports to variable and then add them to new rule that would overwrite existing rule (first command)?

Thanks

---

EDIT
Based on @John Kens code i have written a script. added part with language recognition> so far, only for English and Germain. It would be nice to create something language independent. Maybe next time...

```
 @SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@CD %~dp0

:: get Language ID
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic path win32_OperatingSystem get OSLanguage /Value') do set Language=%%A

echo %Language%

::germain
IF %Language% EQU 1031 ( 
    SET SearchString="Lokaler Port"
) ELSE (
    ::engilsh
    IF %Language% EQU 1033 ( 
    SET SearchString="LocalPort"
    ) ELSE goto :eof
)

echo %SearchString%

::Get the LocalPort to Variable
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="%RULE_NAME%" | findstr %SearchString% > p1o2r3t4.txt
set /P port=<p1o2r3t4.txt
REM del /Q p1o2r3t4.txt

echo port: %port%

::Edit port format from Variable
set eport1=%port: =%
set eport2=%eport1:*Port:=%

echo eport1: %eport1%
echo eport2: %eport2%

::Edit and add new port to existing rule
cls
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="%RULE_NAME%" new localport=%eport2%,%NEW_PORT%
goto :eof
```

Comment: If there's already rules set, you cannot append to them directly, you'd need to retrieve those as a variable or array first, add the information you want to it, then overwrite with everything at once. The biggest issue is likely that it won't take much to reach the maximum command line length. You may want to look and see if there's any existing examples where `PowerShell` has been used to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming your just looking to add ports to existing rule names, the `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule` syntax can be used. However, by defualt of this command, it will overwright existing `port` values. To overcome this, you will need to *grab* the already existing values and set them before the new value in the `1234,2222,1234,NEW_PORT` format.

The script bellow uses a `| findstr` (No way to use an `FOR /F` statement on `netsh advfirewall firewall` in batch) to output the variable to a text file. we then read and tweak using `set value=%%`.

Please keep in mind this script *can* add multiple ports to a single rule at once using the `port1,port2,port3` format. Be sure to run the script as an admin.

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@CD %~dp0

::Check for Admin rights; Exit if no rights
NET SESSION >nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (goto :BEGIN) ELSE (Echo ERROR: You must run as admin. && pause && goto :eof)

:BEGIN
::Ask for rule name & port
set /p RULE_NAME=What rule name do you wish to add port's to: 
set /p NEW_PORT=What port(s) do you wish to add to "%RULE_NAME%": 

::Get the LocalPort to Variable
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="%RULE_NAME%" | findstr "LocalPort" >> p1o2r3t4.txt
set /P port=<p1o2r3t4.txt
del /Q p1o2r3t4.txt

::Edit port format from Variable
set eport1=%port: =%
set eport2=%eport1:LocalPort:=%
echo %eport2%

::Edit and add new port to existing rule
cls
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="%RULE_NAME%" new localport=%eport2%,%NEW_PORT%

pause
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thank you. I have used much of your code, but i had to adapt it little bit to be language independent
<pre>
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic path win32_OperatingSystem get OSLanguage /Value') do set Language=%%A

::germain
IF %Language% EQU 1031 SET SearchString="Lokaler Port"
::engilsh
IF %Language% EQU 1033 SET SearchString="LocalPort"

echo %SearchString%


::Get the LocalPort to Variable
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="%RULE_NAME%" | findstr %SearchString% > p1o2r3t4.txt
set /P port=<p1o2r3t4.txt...

Comment: If you found it useful and had solved your issue, please mark it as solved! @Redundant